# How to set raw body with request-promise-native

Tags: node.js, request-promise

I'm using `request-promise-native` module on node.js. The API I'm calling requires the keys in the header as well as `Content-Type: Application/json`. When using postman to test it, I have to use Body > raw to pass along the necessary parameters. That works just fine.

However, when I try the same with the request library, the body is not being submitted properly. Here's what I've tried:

```
const request = require('request-promise-native')

let options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://api.com',
    headers: {
        'X-Api-Key': <key>,
        'Content-Type': 'Application/json'
    }
}

options.body = {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2'
}

// and since the above didn't work also this:

options.form = {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2'
}


request(options)
   .then(function(res){ /* do something */}
```

I do get a response, but not based on the body paramters. How can I replicate the "raw" body?

Comment: Hey can you add `json: true` to that `options` object and try?

Comment: Or you can try, `Content-Type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` and see if it works.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty thanks, that solves the problem. Want to post it as an answer?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty `json: true` is what solved it

Comment: sure. posting it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `request-promise-native` internally uses `request-promise` which in turn is a wrapper of `request`.
`request` has a option

```
json: true
```

Which is used to pass json body params. You can use it.